I use tf where in my rl a2c implementation for action masking. This leads to nan gradients. Can anyone give me a hint how to implement it properly?

right now I work in an research project where we use reinforcement learning.
Because of the big action and state spaces the vanilla A2C doesn`t work well (for this example and my debugging I restricted the state space to 9 params and the action space to 8 actions).
So I wanted to add action masking (described in this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14171 and this blog post
https://costa.sh/blog-a-closer-look-at-invalid-action-masking-in-policy-gradient-algorithms). In our project we use Tensorflow2 and keras so I tried to translate the Pytorch code shown in the blog post to tf code. To have not to much operations outside of the keras model I added the masking operation to the model.
This are the architectures of the model with and without action masking.


# Environment input
b_env_input = Input(shape=(9,), name="b_env_input")
# Hidden layers
b_hidden_layer_1 = Dense(
    32,
    activation="relu",
    name="b_hidden_layer_1",
)(b_env_input)
b_hidden_layer_2 = Dense(
    32,
    activation="relu",
    name="b_hidden_layer_2",
)(b_hidden_layer_1)
b_hidden_layer_3 = Dense(
    8,
    activation="log_softmax",
    name="b_hidden_layer_3",
)(b_hidden_layer_2)

# Input values which will replace invalid actions, ver small values like -1e+08
b_penalty_value_input = Input(
    shape=(8,), 
    name="b_penalty_value_input",
)

# Mask input with True for invalid actions and False for valid actions
b_penalty_mask_input = Input(
    shape=(8,), 
    name="b_penalty_mask_input",
    dtype="bool"
)

# Masking operation
b_penalty_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.where(
        condition = x[2],
        x = x[0],
        y = x[1]
    ), 
    name="invalid_action_masking",
    output_shape=(8,)
)([b_hidden_layer_3, b_penalty_value_input, b_penalty_mask_input])

dist_out = keras.layers.Softmax()(b_penalty_layer)


b_model = Model(inputs=[b_env_input, b_penalty_value_input, b_penalty_mask_input], outputs=dist_out)

This is the code which is used to produce the model with action masking.
When I try to train the model with action masking the gradients for the
actor model are nearly all nan with very few values being 0.
The critic networks  is trained successfully.
When I run my training code with the actor model without action masking both networks train successfully.
I also tried to use the actor network just to interact with the environment without training. This also worked and already showed significantly better results than the network without invalid action masking.
def train_n_step(self):
    states, next_states, rewards = self.n_step_memory.serve_critic()
    action_indices, penalties = self.n_step_memory.serve_actor()

    inputs = [
                tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(states[-1]).reshape(-1, 9)),
                tf.convert_to_tensor(self.action_masking_values.reshape(-1, 8))),
                tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(penalties[-1]).reshape(-1, 8)))
    ]

     episode_actions_index = tf.constant([action_indices[-1]]) 

     discounted_n_step_rewards = self.calculate_n_step_discounted_reward(rewards)

      with tf.GradientTape() as critic_tape, tf.GradientTape() as actor_tape:
          state_value_predict = self.critic_model(np.array(states[0]).reshape(-1, 9), training=True)
            nth_state_value_predict = self.critic_model(
                np.array(next_states[-1]).reshape(-1, 9),
                training=True
            )
            advantage = discounted_n_step_rewards + \
                self.critic_discount_factor**self.n * nth_state_value_predict - \
                state_value_predict
            critic_loss = tf.square(advantage)

            actor_model_out = self.actor_model(inputs, training=True)
            actor_loss = self.actor_loss(actor_model_out, episode_actions_index, advantage)

        critic_gradients = critic_tape.gradient(critic_loss, self.critic_model.trainable_variables)
        actor_gradients = actor_tape.gradient(actor_loss, self.actor_model.trainable_variables)

        self.critic_model.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(critic_gradients, self.critic_model.trainable_variables)
        )
        self.actor_model.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(actor_gradients, self.actor_model.trainable_variables)
        )

def actor_loss(model_out, action_index, advantage):
        policy_dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=model_out, name="masked_action_distribution")
            
    action_log_prob = policy_dist.log_prob(action_index)

    actor_loss = tf.math.negative(action_log_prob) * tf.convert_to_tensor(advantage)

    return actor_loss

This is a simplified version of my train function. I use TD(n).
The same code (with inputs without action mask and values) works fine for
the model without invalid action masking. So the problem must be the two additional input or the the tf.where operation.
In my opinion this shows that tf autodiff has some problem with the tf.where operation or the sampling and log prob calculation of the sample.
I already searched trough the net and found the following questions/answers regarding this topic:
Another person having problems with nan gradients in context of tf.where 
Another link referenced from the previous question
Issue referenced in previous links
The problem is it is my first project using tf "lowlevel" API's and I don't completely get what is explained in the links.
What I suspect to be the problem is that the tf.where masks the invalid actions with -1e+08. This leads to the probs of this actions being 0 in the softmax output.
When I would take the log of the probs all invalid actions would have an value of -inf.
I hoped that creating an dist out of the probs and just sampling a single sample would prevent the calculation of an log prob of -inf. But the occurence of the nan gradients in my opinion implies that the log prob of 0 was calculated somewhere in the autodiff.
I have tried a lot of different things and nothing worked. Because of my poor tf and autodiff in general knowledge I don`t know what to try next :/
It would be very nice if someone could help me with tis problem.
Thanks in advance!
